# multiple arguments at a time with gnu parallel

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to have GNU parallel to call a command with multiple arguments at a time, up to some limit?

Just for explanations sake, a simple example...

Make some files: 
`seq 10 | parallel touch test_files{}.txt`

To remove them, I could do: `rm ./test_files*.txt`,

or equivalently with GNU parallel: `ls ./test_files*.txt | parallel rm`, 
which runs `rm` once for each file.

Is there some way to tell GNU parallel to run the command with a max-number of arguments, like...

```
ls ./test_files*.txt | parallel --max-args 5 rm
```

that would launch

```
rm test_files1.txt test_files2.txt test_files3.txt test_files4.txt test_files5.txt
rm test_files6.txt test_files7.txt test_files8.txt test_files9.txt test_files10.txt
```

Comment: Or you could use `ls testfiles*.txt | parallel -X rm` which will pass as many files as your OS permits to each invocation of `rm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ seq 10 | parallel --max-args 5 echo
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```